# Github stuck, can't sync, can't revert

Tags: github, commit, github-for-windows

I have a merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master' in my timeline with a dozen changes since then by someone else.

I can't sync. When I try to revert and git revert --continue, it says can't commit because I have unmerged files. No idea what that means.

I looked at the files in question and there are no conflict there (the git comment blocks).

Also, these filed specifically have not been modified by anyone else.

How do I just force Github to take the folder from my current local folder and just move on?

I tried deleting the repository folder and recloning, but then it saied it can't clone. Took a while just to get it to clone. But still can't sync!

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand 100% but if you are just trying to push your local master branch over to Github, I'd try with `git push --force`

Answer (score 0):

Try stashing your changes and then syncing/merging.

`git stash`

`git pull`

`git stash pop`

This should merge your local from upstream and have your changes which you can commit.

Note: In some cases, this might lead to a conflict depending on your code, but that should not be a big problem to solve.

Also, `unmerged` means that you have files that are not committed yet. Do a `git status` and it should show you.

Comment: I tried git status and it says a-ok:

~\Documents\GitHub\goodui [master ≡ +1 ~0 -0 !]> git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        goodui/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. When I tried stash, it said no changes to save. So I rebooted and it seems to sync now. So looks like Github sometimes need a full reboot for some changes to take effect.

Comment: Those `untracked files` is what's giving you the `unmerged files` error. You can add those files using `git add <filename>` (as it says). Git stash temporarily moves your changed files (only changed files) to somewhere else and leaves original unchanged files behind (more specifically, it stores a "patch" that describes changes you made to file). This allows you to sync since your code is virtually unchanged by you. When you `git stash pop`, you are asking it to bring back the changes you made. I am not sure how a reboot fixed your issue, but I am glad that your issue is fixed, regardless.